# Junit integration testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I need help writing a unit test for class `NotificationHandler`. so I made `NotificationHandlerTest` (using junit4) but I don't know how to determine what I should expect as a result versus what the actual result is, so one or more simple test's (for some of its methods) would help me a lot!

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
class NotificationHandler {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private NotificationRoutingRepository routingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SendNotificationGateway gateway;

    @Autowired
    private AccessService accessService;

    @Autowired
    private EndpointService endpointService;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Channels.ASSET_MODIFIED_CHANNEL, poller = @Poller("assetModifiedPoller"), outputChannel = Channels.NULL_CHANNEL)
    public Message<?> handle(Message<EventMessage> message) {
        final EventMessage event = message.getPayload();

        LOG.debug("Generate notification messages: {}, {}", event.getOriginType(), event.getType());

        routingRepository.findByOriginTypeAndEventType(event.getOriginType(), event.getType()).stream()
                .filter(routing -> routing.getOriginId() == null || routing.getOriginId() == event.getOriginId())
                .map(routing -> getNotificationMessages(event, routing))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .forEach(notificationMessage -> {
                    LOG.debug("Sending message {}", notificationMessage);
                    gateway.send(notificationMessage);
                });

        return message;
    }enter code here
    enter code here`enter code here`
    private List<NotificationMessage> getNotificationMessages(EventMessage event, NotificationRouting routing) {
        switch (routing.getDestinationType()) {
            case "USERS":
                LOG.trace("Getting endpoints for users");
                return getEndpointsByUsers(routing, event.getOrigin(), event.getOriginType()).stream()
                        .map(endpoint -> new NotificationMessage(event.getOriginType(), event.getOrigin(), endpoint))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            default:
                LOG.trace("Getting default endpoints");
                return getEndpoints(routing, event.getOrigin(), event.getOriginType()).stream()
                        .map(endpoint -> new NotificationMessage(event.getOriginType(), event.getOrigin(), endpoint))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    private List<Endpoint> getEndpoints(NotificationRouting routing, Object origin, String originType) {
        final Asset asset = getAssetForObject(origin, originType);

        final List<Long> userIds = accessService.list(asset).stream()
                .map(ResourceAccess::getUser)
                .map(AbstractEntity::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        userIds.add(asset.getCreatorId());

        LOG.trace("getEndpoints usersIds {}", userIds);

        final List<Endpoint> endpoints = endpointService.getEndpoints(userIds, routing.getEndpointType());
        LOG.trace("Endpoints {}", endpoints.stream().map(Endpoint::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return endpoints;
    }

    private List<Endpoint> getEndpointsByUsers(NotificationRouting routing, Object origin, String originType) {
        final Asset asset = getAssetForObject(origin, originType);

        final List<Long> userIds = accessService.list(asset).stream()
                .map(ResourceAccess::getUser)
                .map(AbstractEntity::getId)
                .filter(routing.getDestinations()::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        routing.setDestinations(userIds);
        routingRepository.save(routing);

        LOG.trace("getEndpointsByUsers usersIds {}", userIds);

        final List<Endpoint> endpoints = endpointService.getEndpoints(userIds, routing.getEndpointType());
        LOG.trace("Endpoints {}", endpoints.stream().map(Endpoint::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return endpoints;
    }

    private Asset getAssetForObject(Object origin, String originType) {
        switch (originType) {
            case EventMessage.POINT:
                return (Point) origin;
            case EventMessage.FEED:
                return ((Feed) origin).getPoint();
            case EventMessage.ACTUATOR:
                return ((Actuator)origin).getPoint();
            case EventMessage.DEVICE:
                return (Device) origin;
            case EventMessage.ALARM:
                return ((Alarm) origin).getPoint();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + originType);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You **DO** need to know what the class you are testing does and  the expected behavior of its methods.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: Welcome to SO. please show what you have tried so far and ask specific question, so we can give you specific answers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you start with a simple test if you're not sure what to test. One test that verifies you don't get any exception if you send `null` as an argument.

E.g.

```
@Test
public void shouldNotThrowAnyExceptionIfArgumentIsNull() {
  // given
  NotificationHandler handler = new NotificationHandler();
  // when
  handler.handle(null);
  // then no exception is thrown.
}
```

After that, you can analyze line by line what the method `handle` is doing and write tests that verify its behavior.

You can, for example, verify that the method `gateway.send(...);` was executed or not depending on what you sent in the parameter.

For dependency mocking and behavior verification, I'd recommend you use `mockito` or a similar tool.
You can follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) tutorial to learn how to do it.